# Organizing Nodejs Apps: Content sperated from HTML?

Tags: node.js, content-management-system

Is there some kind of best-practice for organizing Nodejs apps regarding to content management? 
It seems pretty bad to me when "hardcoding" the content (especially text) directly inside the jade or ejs template. My experience is that this is not quite maintainable (at least for larger projects).

Should all the content be served from a seperated content directory next to the views?

```
| appRoot
| -- public
| -- views
     | -- index.ejs
     | -- user.ejs
| -- content
     | -- index.json
     | -- user.json
```

But this has some downsides as well: what about links, custom styling, and that stuff? Defining these inside the content *.json seems bad to me as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using json as models but I am using markdown in jade templates. I like a separate directory because that is common practice in MVC style apps, and it provides separation of the models from the views.

I'm finding that it is easy to refactor file paths in node using webstorm, so you can change the dir structure later too.